# Сайт на вордпрессе, есть яндекс карта с метками, на андроиде метки на карте видны, а на айфоне нет. почему?

Tags: wordpress, яндекс-карты

Сайт на вордпрессе, есть яндекс карта с метками (кастомные), на андроиде метки на карте видны, а на айфоне нет.
через девтулс все корректно, ошибок в консоли нет
возможно кто-то сталкивался ?

На просторах интернета нашла вариант заменить кастомную метку на дефолтную. Замена ни к чему не привела

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: метки созданы следующим образом: 

let myCollectionMobile = new ymaps.GeoObjectCollection(
    {},
    {
       iconLayout: "default#image",
       iconImageHref: "/Location-4.png",
       iconImageSize: [18, 27],
       draggable: false,
    }
    );
myCollectionMobile.add(myPlaceMarkMobile)


при просмотре страницы с андроида метки есть, с айфона их нет на карте. отображается только карта

Comment: После публикации вопроса вы можете его редактировать, лучше не в комментарии вносить пояснения, а изменить сам вопрос. Там больше инструментария для оформления.